# How to use Phantomjs for opening a website in Selenium

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to use headless webkit of PhantomJs for opening google.com through selenium webdriver but when I execute the code system throws an error. phantomJs.exe is placed in E directory. Please help me resolve this issue.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
                caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);  
   caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "E:\\phantomjs.exe");
                WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();              
                driver.get("http://www.google.com");

            }
```

**Error:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the phantomjs.binary.path capability/system property/PATH variable; for more information, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki. The latest version can be downloaded from http://phantomjs.org/download.html
>       at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.findPhantomJS(PhantomJSDriverService.java:236)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:181)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.(PhantomJSDriver.java:104)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.(PhantomJSDriver.java:94)
>       at multidrivers.main(multidrivers.java:35)

Comment: Hint: Where do the capabilities go?

Comment: I'm not able to get you. Is there anything which I've missed?

Comment: @ArtjomB. means did u add your capability to driver?

Comment: @Manu Obviously. Why else would you define the capabilities, but never use them? Just pass them to the driver. Docs: http://cdn.ivandemarino.me/phantomjsdriver-javadoc/org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs/PhantomJSDriver.html#PhantomJSDriver%28org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities%29

Comment: Which part of "The path to the driver executable must be set by the **phantomjs.binary.path**" and "for more information, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki " are you having problems with?

Comment: It would be better if anyone can correct my above mentioned code and make it working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the phantomjs.binary.path capability/system property/PATH variable;

The above issue is due to the driver not being initialized with the DesiredCapabilities object:

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
```

Updating the code as below should solve your issue:

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful but when I included the change I got the following error.                                                                                     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/browserlaunchers/Proxies
 at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService.createDefaultService(PhantomJSDriverService.java:178)
 at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:99)
 at Phantom.main(Phantom.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.browserlaunchers.Proxies

Comment: Are you using proxy? Kindly update the question according given the code where this error occur. If you are using Selenium v 2.44.0, you may need to upgrade selenium or phantom.js, there seems to a compatibility issue. [Link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8088)

Comment: Thanks once again. I was using selenium 2.44 now i've upgraded it to 2.46 its working but when I used it the execution of program didn't stop I mean to say on eclipse console "Stop" button remained active. I think the phantomjs driver thread remains active so is there any way other than System.exit(0) to stop the execution?

Comment: You should close the driver using `driver.quit();` else it will remain in memory.

Comment: This isn't a solution anymore. Class PhantomJSDriver takes its DesiredCapabilities object, if it's not provided in the constructor and calls the appropriate constructor. `public PhantomJSDriver() {
        this(DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs());
    }`